# Assigning a float to subset returns 1

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, subset, slice

I'm trying to assign a float `0.3` to a subset in pandas but the result returns the value `1`. But if I assign an integer like `12` it will return `12`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['A','B','C','D'],
    'Val1': [1,2,3,4],
    'Val2': [5,6,7,8]
})

df.set_index('A', inplace=True)
df.loc[:'D', 'Val1'].iloc[:-1] = 0.3 // returns 1 instead of 0.3
```

Comment: At which position are you trying to assign the value? The problem is not with assigning a float but with the syntax of loc

Comment: Try df.iloc[:3, 0] = 0.3

Answer (score 2):

The way that you're using `loc` is strange, I wouldn't recommend chaining calls to `iloc` and `loc`, instead, correctly slice the DataFrame:

```
df.loc[:-1, 'Val1'] = 0.3
```

```
   Val1  Val2
A
A   0.3     5
B   0.3     6
C   0.3     7
D   4.0     8
```

Or explicitly:

```
df.loc['A':'C', 'Val1'] = 0.3
```

Comment: Agreed. I'm chaining the `loc` and `iloc` because I wanted to subset everything up to `C` but _excluding_ `C` itself.

Edit: Index is a dynamic range of dates so I won't always know the start/end points

Answer (score 0):

Works if you cast `Val1` to float type first:

```
df.Val1 = df.Val1.astype(float)
```

Full example:

```
df.set_index('A', inplace=True)
df.Val1 = df.Val1.astype(float)
df.loc[:'D', 'Val1'].iloc[:-1] = 0.3 
print(df)
```

[output]

```
   Val1  Val2
A            
A   0.3     5
B   0.3     6
C   0.3     7
D   4.0     8
```

However, I have to agree with @user3483203... See his answer on best practice for using `loc` and `iloc` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

#### `loc`

```
df.loc[df.index[:-1], 'Val1'] = .3
df

   Val1  Val2
A            
A   0.3     5
B   0.3     6
C   0.3     7
D   4.0     8
```

---

#### `iloc`

```
df.iloc[:-1, df.columns.get_loc('Val1')] = .4
df

   Val1  Val2
A            
A   0.4     5
B   0.4     6
C   0.4     7
D   4.0     8
```